# Downloading a file via Axios from Django

Tags: django, axios

I'm trying to get filename from blob request using Axios and Django.

Django's view:

```
with open(full_file_path, 'rb') as f:   
    response = HttpResponse(f, content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')  
    file_expr = "filename*=utf-8''{}".format(quote(file_name_with_ext))  
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; {}'.format(file_expr)  
return response
```

Frontend:

```
axios
    .request({
        url,
        method,
        responseType: 'blob',
    })
    .then(({ data }) => {
        console.log(data);
        const downloadUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data]));
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.href = downloadUrl;
        link.setAttribute('download', 'file.xlsx');
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        link.remove();
    });
```

But parameter 'data' doesn't contain headers to allow me to get filename.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of this `.then(({ data }) => {` Use this:`.then(response =>{`

and `response.data` is your data from response that you can see with `console.log(response.data);`

Hope it helps<3.